# How to read live video feed or video on demand feed in python?

Tags: python, computer-vision

I need to read live video feed as well any video feed URL in Python.  This is input for a machine learning project.
I used the `cv.VideoCapture` method. It didn't work for me.
I tried many StackOverflow links, but found no solution.

Please help to read live/normal video URL I in python. I tried with below snippet code.

```
import cv2
url = 'https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4'
camera = cv2.VideoCapture()
print("open:",camera.open(url)) # False
print("read:",camera.read()) # (False, None)
```

output:

```
open: False
read: (False, None)
```

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://www.learnopencv.com/read-write-and-display-a-video-using-opencv-cpp-python/).

You need to pass your url in `VideoCapture(url)`.

**For your question:**

```
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'3.4.2'
>>> cap = cv2.VideoCapture("https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4")
")

  
>>> cap.read()
(True, array([[[ 46, 112, 104],
        [ 31,  97,  89],
        [ 21,  92,  83],
        ...,

       [[ 62, 153, 159],
        [ 68, 159, 165],
        [ 70, 158, 165],
        ...,
        [ 33, 121, 114],
        [ 28, 131, 113],
        [ 42, 145, 127]]], dtype=uint8))
>>> cap.release()
>>> cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Below code is referenced from document,

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
 
# Create a VideoCapture object and read from input file
# If the input is the camera, pass 0 instead of the video file name
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('chaplin.mp4')
 
# Check if camera opened successfully
if (cap.isOpened()== False): 
  print("Error opening video stream or file")
 
# Read until video is completed
while(cap.isOpened()):
  # Capture frame-by-frame
  ret, frame = cap.read()
  if ret == True:
 
    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('Frame',frame)
 
    # Press Q on keyboard to  exit
    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
      break
 
  # Break the loop
  else: 
    break
 
# When everything done, release the video capture object
cap.release()
 
# Closes all the frames
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Haha ("1 min google search"). Thanks for helping Shaik. Please read the problem statement again. Your answer is not relevant to me.

Comment: I passed URL into VideoCapture(url). it didn't work as I mentioned in my problem statement already.

Comment: For camera, you need to pass `0` in `VideoCapture`.

Comment: I am not using a camera. I need to run the video through URL only.

Comment: For me its working. `CV2.__version__ == 3.4.2`. Can you check the version? Try to capture the error. It will be easy to debug.

Comment: For me, it is 4.1.0

Comment: Can we use colab.research.google.com for running the same code?

Comment: I have also faced issue, when 3.4.2 version is latest. Try to consider stable version of CV2, cuz there are 1604 issues are opened in github. And we are here in SO to help each other not to degrade. Happy coding :)